# Why Grails keep saying: "unable to resolve class" randomly, for no reason?

Tags: grails

This bug or my lack-of-knowledge or smth else is really starting to bother me. I am working on a Grails app and randomly in the middle of my work, grails with complain about some import, saying that cannot resolve the class name. It was working one save ago! I havent changed anything to the infrastructure of the project. I've just written more code. the bothering part is that the app still runs fine, it's just that it has two tagging Xses and every time I start it, I need to press "proceed with errors". I have to refactor the class names to smth else and then back again to the original name. that fixes it and takes a lot of time. Am I missing smth here?

Comment: 1. Are you experiencing this while you have the app running with 'grails run-app' and you are editing code or when starting the project fresh after changes?

2. What do you mean by "two tagging Xses"?

3. have you tried 'grails clean' ?

(Edited this comment because I didn't remember that enter = post)

Comment: 1. I experience the problem whatever I do. It doesnt get fixed unless I refactor the two class names and factor them back.
2. I have 2 Xes, because I have two imports in my Bootstrap.groovy from two other domain classes. each "import blabla" has a leading red X in front of it (i.e. error)
3. I have tried  both clean and refresh dependencies

Comment: I just learned that it also gets fixed if I exclude and then include the problematic classes from the buildpath

Comment: I have the same issue, but a grails clean followed by a project clean seems to clear it up.

Comment: I know how to do 'ctrl+alt+shift+g -> clean', but i dont know how to do "Project Clean".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comments under the question seems like you are using Eclipse or STS. If that is the case then I was experiencing the same problem with older versions of STS or to be more precise with older versions of Groovy-Eclipse plugin.

I think I haven't seen that happening since STS 2.7 (I'm now using STS 2.8 with Groovy-Eclipse 2.6), so try upgrading. It's IDE bug not the Grails problem itself (at least it was in my case).

Comment: well, apparently i can't update STS. it gives me: An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=com.springsource.sts.ide, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Comparison method violates its general contract!
Comparison method violates its general contract!